# Copy daily results from SELECT query into other table or db

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-agent-job

I have large SELECT query that return daily report, as a stored function with

```
DECLARE @timeStamp datetime2 = '22.02.2017'
```

or

```
DECLARE @timeStamp datetime2 = GETDATE()
```

What can be solution, to have data for all dates in the past, and also for future dates, that can fill some new table with results, or some other DB/sometable on same server. Do I ned to use SSIS or can I accomplish that with SQL Schedules, and Agent.

Database is in SQL Server 2014 on-premise

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If the destination and source database are in the same SQL Server/instance, you can just write some stored procedures insert the data, something like

```
INSERT INTO destdb.dbo.tablename
(Col1
, Col2
)
SELECT Col1
, Col2
FROM sourcedb.dbo.tablename;
```

Then add a new SQL job under SQL Agent, and scheduled it.

If destination and source data are not in the same SQL Server, you may need SSIS to move the data.